# Adding classes to divs in viewport (Tolerances)

Tags: javascript, jquery, view, scroll

I am using the following script to find if any div with the class ".wew" are in viewport view and if so, it will add the class "inview".

This works great but I'm using full screen height divs and it's adding the class to 2 divs at once, probably because it's checking if the div is visible at the top or bottom of the screen. Is there a way to amend it where it will only activate if the div is within 100px of the top of the window?

CODE:

```
$.fn.visible = function(partial, hidden) {

var $t = $(this).eq(0),
  t = $t.get(0),
  $w = $(window),
  viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
  viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
  _top = $t.offset().top,
  _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
  compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
  compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom,
  clientSize = hidden === true ? t.offsetWidth * t.offsetHeight : true;

return !!clientSize && ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop)); }; 

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  $(".wew").each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("inview"); 
    } else {
      el.removeClass("inview");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: did you write this code or did you copy it from somewhere? did you try anything? seems like if you got this far on your own it should be pretty straightforward to add the 100px threshold.

Comment: I got it from somewhere else I'm afraid

Comment: dont be afraid :P and thanks for being honest. generally people will be more inclined to help if you make some effort. even a random wild guess. that tells us that you're not just looking for someone to write free code for you. also, could you clarify the question, "within 100px of the top of the viewport" .. if an element is 50px above the viewport (not visible) it's still within 100px..

Comment: I don't know where to start to be honest. I'm not looking for anyone to do the work for me but if someone knows with an explanation I'll then know for next time.

Comment: No effort to do it yourself, no effort to even answer my request for clarification. Voting to close. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise you were asking a question. I am trying to figure out the issue myself by reading up but haven't found anything yet. By 100px I mean when the top of the screen scrolls 100px vertically in to the div, it would activate and deactivate 100px before it leaves.

Comment: Ok, close vote retracted. If my answer helped you please don't forget to hit the checkmark. Good luck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your code here, but the main difference is that I added a threshold to the top and subtracted a threshold from the bottom threshold. As you scroll you'll notice that only items that are more than the threshold from the top or the bottom get the class applied..

Note that you can adjust the threshold by changing the 50 to 100 or whatever you need: `el.isWithinThreshold(50)`

```js
$.fn.isWithinThreshold = function(threshold) {
  var $t = $(this).eq(0),
    t = $t.get(0),
    $w = $(window),
    viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
    viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
    _top = $t.offset().top,
    _bottom = _top + $t.height()
  return (_bottom <= viewBottom - threshold) && (_top >= threshold + viewTop);
};

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  $(".wew").each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.isWithinThreshold(50)) {
      el.addClass("inview");
    } else {
      el.removeClass("inview");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.wew {
  border: 1px solid black
}

.inview {
  border: 5px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
<div class='wew'>stuff</div>
```